# Minimizing the norm of a vector of parameters

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

I'm reading a [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1011.4071.pdf) that defines a function $f_w(x)$ that takes input $x$ and parameters $w$ and a set of constraints. There are also training data. The aim is to find the set of parameters $w$ that respect the constraints. The authors then defined the optimization problem as the following:

$min_w F(w) = ||w||^2$ with respect to the constraints.

My question is thus, why minimizing the squared norm of the parameters vector $w$ returns the optimal solution? Why minimization? why the norm of the parameters vector?

Comment: This is similar to the way [support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) work.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the specific function $f_w(x)$. But as Marc Claesen points out, one example of this is the SVM setting. Here, the norm $\|w\|^2$ has a natural interpretation as the reciprocal of the margin of the classifier. Minimizing this allows you to find a large-margin classifier.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to minimizing the distance in an SVM, it can also be thought of promoting parsimony; cf. [Tikhonov regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)